# Will I lose all of my external HDD data while installing Ubuntu 20?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 20.04, external-hdd

I have a 256 GB SSD with Windows 10 installed on it and am trying to install Ubuntu on my external 4 TB HDD,which has only about 1 TB full. Now, while I am installing Ubuntu, I have to choose the third option **something else** to be able of installing Ubuntu on the external HDD. When I choose this option, I arrive to where partitions are made. While the external HDD is on the list, I cannot really make any changes on it using the **plus button** as the external HDD has its used and free space unknown. When I click on the **minus button** however, it takes a second, reareads the various discs and suddenly my 4TB HDD has 4 HDD free space ready for partition.
I have already made two partitions, one for the root and a swap one that I do not really understand its purpose. I have not yet clicked on **install now** If I click it, will I lose everything on the external HDD or not?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you do not get a solid answer I would experiment using an external drive which you are free to destroy then build up experience

Comment: I was going to do so, however, my second external HDD has fallen two days ago and is not working no more.

Comment: You will not loose data if you do not destroy the partition. In any case, you have a very good backup of your data. Installing an operating system always entails a risk that something goes wrong (human error or software or hardware failure), so do not proceed before your backup copies are up to date.

Comment: be aware that attempting to install a boot-able external disc can alter your main host OS if you are not extremely careful rendering the main computer non bootable ... as an aside I would say that external HDD which stopped working is probably fixable it may just be a software issue

Comment: Quite easy to lose all data, also quite easy to install and keep all data.  As vanadium said should have data backup.  Know what you are doing and what partition you want to use.  Many sites and videos online on installing ubuntu.

Comment: The broken external you have, the actual drive might be okay.  Can try removing drive from enclosure and put it in a known working enclosure to test.  Best case if drive was not in use(writing/reading) when it fell.

Comment: It is true that there are many sources on installing Ubuntu, however, all discuss only empty external HDDs. I will not take the risk and lose all of the data. I will find a used HDD somewhere and use it to test probably. Note, the other HDD's read/ write head is broken.